# What is the difference between prototype and Class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I have seen in a tutorial that prototype and class almost same in javasript. but there has diffrence betwwen them. my idea about prototype is not clear. Can you give a clear understanding about that?

Comment: Did you google the same ?

Comment: @rmalviya It seems that OP wonders about ES6 classes, not sure this duplicates the question you linked.

Comment: No, we cannot give you a clear understanding, because for that we needed to know what is unclear about prototypes for you.